# Compile from source

Tags: monerod, build

What are the steps we need to do if we want to compile the codes of the repository ? I want to compile and run the monero or crypto note repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are instructions in the github repo: https://github.com/monero-project/monero#compiling-monero-from-source

If you get stuck, I suggest asking the specific question to help you move forward, with your OS specified and steps taken so far.